# Pullinging data from xml page

Tags: xml

Hi i am trying to get some information from this page http://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/blueprints/xml/598/35/5 i need "actualquantity".

i am using google docs excel doc. trying to import it with importxml.

this is what i have got so far:

=ImportXML(http://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/blueprints/xml/598/35/5?,"//totalmaterials[@id='34']//actualquantity")

just to make sure you know what i am trying to do here is get the actualquantity numbers printed out in a cell.

i tried googleing it to no avail.

i was thinking this would be simple for someone that knows what they are doing.

thanks for the help.

ben

Answer (score 0):

your XPath needs to include the full path to the target element you are after. I put this into Google Documents and got a list of data back:

```
=importXml("http://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/blueprints/xml/598/35/5"; "//blueprint/basematerials/material/@actualquantity")
```

If you are after a specific element as you demonstrated in your question do exactly as you were and slot in the id filter:

```
=importXml("http://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/blueprints/xml/598/35/5"; "//blueprint/basematerials/material[@id='34']/@actualquantity")
```

Comment: yeah thanks thats perfect. it appears i have got a lot to learn.

Comment: the next question would be how would i be able to use the =transpose function to display id=34 id=35 ect.

Comment: If you use the importXml function to grab the ids in column 'A' and then another importXml function for the values in 'B', then you can navigate somewhere else on your spreadsheet and punch in a formula like =transpose(A1:B5).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Excel part of this, but I put your data into a local file, added a DTD, and used the following query:

```
    doc("actual_quantity-with-dtd.xml")//totalmaterials/material/(data(@id), ",",data(@actualquantity),",")
```

which gave the following output that you can import as a csv file into Excel.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>34 , 16043 , 35 , 13537 , 36 , 2507 , 37 , 100 , 39 , 2 , 38 , 2 , 40 , 1 ,
```